# Celery Send Email on Due_date

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

Sending email to the users based on the due date in model using the celery, the due_date is something different from date when a task is created

**Models.py**

```
class Task(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@shared_task
def send_email():
    today = datetime.now()
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(due_date__date=today)
    for task in tasks:
        # Send email task
```

Run this task daily. Celery Beat makes running periodic tasks easy - https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-custom-schedulers

Comment: Thanks for the answer as i told the date is not today i should send mail on due_date lets say the due_date in the model is set to 07/07/2022 the mail should be sent on that particular date

Comment: When the task is run every day, when today's date hits 07/07/2022, it will send the email.